# Buckbuild tutorials (in order to get nuclide and react.native) running

Tags: android, ios, react-native, buck

I am developing react native since some time. Now i want to switch from visual studio code to atom. I found the nuclide plugin.

Now i am trying to get the full featureset of this ide. But i am stuck at the setup of buckbuild.

Actually i have no idea how to integrate buckbuild with my existing react native projects. Its all about trail and error. Well and this comsumes too much time. I find the documentation of buck really bad.

**Does anybody have some links to some 'working' github repos or some tutorials that explain the integration of buck into react native projects?**

(I am highlighting working, because i found some links, but none of them are working)